# How to get click event of keyboard in android?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Is their any way to get click event of keyboard in android? Actually I am developing one app and need the click event of the keyboard. Example, if user press the alphabets 'a' from keyboard in android phone then I want the click event of 'a'. Recently I came across the onKeyListener and used the various KeyCode, but eventually it didn't helped me.

```
public class KeyCode {


    private Context con;
    private EditText edt;
    private ArrayList<String> array;


    public KeyCode(Context con, final ArrayList<String> array, final EditText edt)
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.array=array;
        this.con=con;
        this.edt=edt;


        edt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_A)
                {
                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(0));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(26));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_B)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(1));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(27));
                    }

                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_C)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(2));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(28));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_D)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(3));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(29));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_E)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(4));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(30));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_F)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(5));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(31));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_G)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(6));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(32));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_H)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(7));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(33));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_I)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(8));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(34));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_J)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(9));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(35));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_K)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(10));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(36));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_L)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(11));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(37));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_M)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(12));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(38));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_N)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(13));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(39));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_O)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(14));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(40));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_P)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(15));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(41));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_Q)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(16));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(42));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_R)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(17));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(43));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_S)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(18));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(44));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_T)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(19));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(45));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_U)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(20));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(46));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_V)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(21));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(47));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_W)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(22));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(48));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_X)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(23));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(49));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_Y)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(24));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(50));
                    }
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_Z)
                {

                    if(event.isCapsLockOn())
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(25));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edt.append(array.get(51));
                    }
                }


                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_0)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(52));
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_1)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(53));
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_2)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(54));
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_3)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(55));
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_4)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(56));
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_5)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(57));
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_6)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(58));
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_7)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(59));
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_8)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(60));
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_9)
                {
                    edt.append(array.get(61));
                }

                /*if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_DEL)
                {
                    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                            edt.setText(s);

                        }
                    });
                }*/

                /*if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_SPACE)
                {
                    edt.append(" ");
                }*/

                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_COMMA)
                {
                    edt.append(",");
                }

                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_PERIOD)
                {
                    edt.append(".");
                }

                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_EQUALS)
                {
                    edt.append("=");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_LEFT_BRACKET)
                {
                    edt.append("(");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_RIGHT_BRACKET)
                {
                    edt.append(")");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_SEMICOLON)
                {
                    edt.append(";");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_APOSTROPHE)
                {
                    edt.append("'");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_GRAVE)
                {
                    edt.append("~");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_SLASH)
                {
                    edt.append("/");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DIVIDE)
                {
                    edt.append("/");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_MULTIPLY)
                {
                    edt.append("*");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_SUBTRACT)
                {
                    edt.append("-");
                }
                if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ADD)
                {
                    edt.append("+");
                }



                return true;
            }
        });

    }



}
```

This is what my java class is. I have an array of certain characters and I do pass it to this java file to replace the default characters with characters contained in array. The characters are replaced but when the key is pressed from the laptop keyboard not from the keyboard of the android phone.

```
public class ChangeFont extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText edt;
    private ImageView img1,img2,img3,img4,img5;
    private ListView lst, savelist;
    private TextView txtNew,txtSave;
    private DataBaseHelper data;
    private ArrayList<String> category;
    private ArrayList<String> styleArray;
    private Cursor c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_font);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fonts");
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);



        data=new DataBaseHelper(this);
        edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
        img3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);
        img4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image4);
        img5=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image5);

        lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        savelist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.savelist);

        txtNew=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textnew);
        txtSave=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textsave);

        category=new ArrayList<String>();
        styleArray=new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            data.createDataBase();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        c=data.getSample();


        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            while(!c.isAfterLast())
            {
                String cat = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseUtil.SAMPLE));


                category.add(cat);

                c.moveToNext();

            }
        }


        /*l=data.getAllLockType();

        if (l.moveToFirst())
        {
            while(!l.isAfterLast())
            {

                String cat=l.getString(l.getColumnIndex(DataBaseUtil.LOCK_TYPE));

                Log.i("String",""+cat);
                locktype.add(cat);

                l.moveToNext();

            }
        }

        Log.i("Lock Array",""+locktype);*/

        SampleStyleAdapter aa=new SampleStyleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), category);

        lst.setAdapter(aa);



        lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                data.openDataBase();

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(edt, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);


                final String stylename = category.get(position).toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + stylename + "position" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                List<DataBaseModel> sy = data.getStyle(position);


                styleArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (DataBaseModel model : sy) {
                    String vimal = model.getStyle();

                    styleArray.add(vimal);
                }

                Log.i("Style Array", "" + styleArray);


                KeyCode key=new KeyCode(getApplicationContext(),styleArray,edt);
                //Log.i("Called Key Code","Class");



            }
        });

        edt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                lst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                savelist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edt.requestFocus();
                edt.setCursorVisible(true);
                //InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                //imm.showSoftInput(edt, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            }
        });

        img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                lst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                savelist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtNew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                edt.setCursorVisible(false);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edt.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        });

        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                lst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edt.requestFocus();
                edt.setCursorVisible(true);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(edt, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);


            }
        });

        img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i=new Intent(ChangeFont.this, EmojiTabbed.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        img4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                lst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                savelist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtNew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                edt.setCursorVisible(false);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edt.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        });

        img5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i=new Intent(ChangeFont.this, Share.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_change_font, menu);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:

                Intent i=new Intent(this, Home.class);
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, i);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Whether this thing is possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Click event occur for mouse click or touch down and for you need to capture key down event  like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          //back button key up
      }
return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

and for click event you should use this

```
yourControl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
       // your code
    }
});
```

i hop this will help you

Comment: Sorry this thing also I tried, but didn't helped me.. @sourabhdevpura

Comment: @VimalDiwani This is the core of event if you use this exact click event witch i posted i will definitely work .

Comment: i need click event of all alphabets and number from android keyboard. @sourabhdevpura

Comment: @VimalDiwani in this cas you just need to remove this line from your code if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_A) and then you code will execute on any keypress

Comment: if i remove that code then how will I replace the the character at KEYCODE_A with the character in the array? @sourabhdevpura

Comment: @VimalDiwani i min that i you want to execute your cone on any key press you don't need to compare with those key enum and then after execute  the part of your code witch is common for every key press you can  compare the key event as per your requirement

Comment: See I have an array of 62 characters which consists of Capital alphabets(26) , small alphabets(26) and numbers(0-9). I would like to replace default characters what the android provides with the characters I have in my array. So for that i was thinking to get the key event of the key pressed from the android phone keyboard. @sourabhdevpura

Comment: @VimalDiwani r u building your own android key board ? then y u re not using HashMap<> simple create a HashMap with key value pair where key will be the main enum provided my the Java like Keys.A and value will be your own characters the if some one press 'G' you just need to pick the value from your HashMap where Key is 'G'

Comment: @VimalDiwani and for create HashMap read this  http://www.javatpoint.com/HashMap-class-in-collection-framework

Comment: Can you give me a small example from code itself. It would be glad. Will you please? Thanks in advance @sourabhdevpura

Comment: I don't wanna design a keyboard for android phones. I just simply need to replace the default characters. The characters in array are of different style.   Eg: [Ⓐ, Ⓑ, Ⓒ, Ⓓ, Ⓔ,.....]  @sourabhdevpura

Comment: @VimalDiwani Ok then accept my answer then mail me your 65 character array on my mail id sdevpura5@gmail.com i will sent you example code in replay in 2-3 hours

Comment: @VimalDiwani Check your Mail

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the clicked key characters   by keycodes** :

```
List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
            for (Key key : keys) {

                if (key.codes[0] == 65) { //A

                }   }
```

For Reference
http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

Comment: Your method getKeyboard() cannot be resolved. @AnilMeenugu